# Mechanism of the reaction of cyclohexanol and concentrated nitric acid to form adipic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, organic-oxidation

If someone could please give me the hint to how the initial attack is carried out, it'd be a huge help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the article by van Asselt and van Krevelen [[1](https://doi.org/10.1002/recl.19630820107)]:

1. Cyclohexanol is oxidized to cyclohexanone.
2. The cyclohexanone reacts with the nitrous acid to yield isonitrosocyclohexanone producing 2-nitro-2-nitrosocyclohexanone by reaction with nitric acid.
3. With attendant ring opening and uptake of water the latter compound is transformed into 6-hydroxyimino-6-nitro hexanoic acid.
4. More than 90% of it is converted to adipic acid.

> [image: Scheme of the adipic acid synthesis]

#### References

1. van Asselt, W. J.; van Krevelen, D. W. Preparation of Adipic Acid by Oxidation of Cyclohexanol and Cyclohexanone with Nitric Acid: Part I. Reaction Mechanism. *Recl. Trav. Chim. Pays-Bas* **1963**, 82 (1), 51–67. DOI: [10.1002/recl.19630820107](https://doi.org/10.1002/recl.19630820107).